# React Native: Cannot find android/app folder

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I am following the tutorial to sign an apk for a native react app:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

But I can't locate the android/app where I am supposed to edit some files.

I tried using this path: ~project\node_modules\react-native\ReactAndroid
I can see the files mentioned from the previous step, but then I run:

gradlew assembleRelease

And I get:

> startup failed:
>     build file '~project\node_modules\react-native\ReactAndroid\build.gradle': 8: unable to resolve class de.undercouch.gradle.tasks.download.Download
>      @ line 8, column 1.
>        import de.undercouch.gradle.tasks.download.Download

So my guess is, I am at the wrong path, could you point me to where is the android/app folder I'm looking for?

Comment: Did you create project via creact-react-native-app?

Comment: Yes, I even try to create another empty project with the same command, but I don't get that folder, it loads a bunch of node_modules only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `create-react-native-app` help to build app without configuration (no `ios` and `android` folder).

If you want to config more. run [`npm run eject`](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app#npm-run-eject) or [`yarn eject`](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app#npm-run-eject) in your project. After run that command folder `ios` and `android` will show up. But it will change your project structure.

Another way, you can build signed apk with [expo](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app#how-do-i-get-my-app-into-the-play-storeapp-store) (It's not change your project structure)

Comment: Both answers are correct, I actually had expo (for testing in my device) I didn't know I could use it to sign and create an apk. If it helps someone, I actually tested both options by having a copy of my project and everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

did you run

```
cd android
```

command before running

```
gradlew assembleRelease
```

or you can run them in 1 command like

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Comment: I did, both separate and together, when together I get me the 'The system cannot find the path specified'. when I run only gradlew assembleRelease,I get the error from the question, please let me know if you have any other idea, thanks